# How to save the changes database via QSqlTableModel?

Tags: c++, database, qt

I changed the value of cell in my Table:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("sqlite.db");
db.open();

QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, db);
model->setTable("Expenses");
model->select();
model->setData(model->index(0,2), 100);
```

How now to save the changes in the database (sqlite.db)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#setData) says, saving changes depends on edit strategy settings of your model. Depending on the edit strategy, the value might be applied to the database at once or cached in the model.
You should refer to the `QSqlTableModel::setEditStrategy()` function of your model and set up the one that corresponds to your needs. For example, if you set edit strategy to `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange`, all changes will apply immediately after `setData()` function call.

Otherwise, you simply need to call `QSqlTableModel::submitAll()` to submit all pending changes to the database.